# Xcode 10 crash with spritekit scene file .sks

Tags: ios, xcode, scenekit

Most of my Sprite Kit scenes are unable to be read; Xcode just crashes. I tried deleting the names. Nothing seems to work.

A new project randomly crashes when I put a texture on a SKSpriteNode. Sometimes I can put three textures before it crashes, sometimes the same first texture has it crash.

[Full log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Cm_FFheJxIl8QWBPyfaBzyl1j5bQ8KZ0/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Are you using `Objective-C` or `Swift`?

Comment: I am using Swift (4.2 but it was swift 3 at beginning)

Comment: Hi, do you found how to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Mac OS in a virtual machine, then it’s a known issue. *.sks files crash when running Xcode in a virtual machine.

Comment: I don't have a virtual machine